# How to add DropListener to drop text in a draw2d Label

Tags: eclipse-gef, draw2d

I am Trying to add a dropListener so I can Drop and text into a draw2d Label ,in GEf Editor , Can anyone help how Can I do that. An example will be great.

Answer (score 0):

To respond to drop events on a GEF edit part viewer you have to install on the viewer itself an implementation of `org.eclipse.jface.util.TransferDropTargetListener` that understands transfers of type `org.eclipse.swt.dnd.TextTransfer` and that creates some kind of `org.eclipse.gef.Request` that can be handled by an `org.eclipse.gef.EditPolicy` installed on the target `org.eclipse.gef.EditPart`.

You have to understand that both the `Request` and the `EditPolicy` allow you to customize the drop behavior on a `EditPart` basis. As a consequence, I can show you an example that is actually fully functional, but feel free to customize it to your real needs.

First create the `TransferDropTargetListener`:

```
public class TextTransferDropTargetListener extends AbstractTransferDropTargetListener {

    public TextTransferDropTargetListener(EditPartViewer viewer) {
        super(viewer, TextTransfer.getInstance());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleDragOver() {
        getCurrentEvent().feedback = DND.FEEDBACK_SCROLL | DND.FEEDBACK_EXPAND;
        super.handleDragOver();
    }

    @Override
    protected Request createTargetRequest() {
        return new ChangeBoundsRequest(REQ_ADD);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateTargetRequest() {
        ChangeBoundsRequest request = (ChangeBoundsRequest) getTargetRequest();
        request.setEditParts(Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
        request.setLocation(getDropLocation());
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleDrop() {
        super.handleDrop();
        if (getCurrentEvent().detail != DND.DROP_NONE) {
            getViewer().setSelection(StructuredSelection.EMPTY);
            getViewer().getControl().setFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Command getCommand() {
        String text = (String) getCurrentEvent().data; 
        List<IEntityPart> editParts = new ArrayList<IEntityPart>();

        //
        // using the 'text' variable you have to create
        // a new EditPart that would eventually replace the old one.
        //
        editParts.add(createNewLabelPart());

        ChangeBoundsRequest request = (ChangeBoundsRequest) getTargetRequest();
        request.setEditParts(editParts);

        return super.getCommand();
    }
}
```

then install the listener in the graphical viewer constructor using the following statement:

```
addDropTargetListener(new TextTransferDropTargetListener(this));
```

finally ensure that an `EditPolicy` that understands requests of type `REQ_ADD` (maybe you already added one that extends `LayoutEditPolicy` or `ContainerEditPolicy`) is installed on the target `EditPart`, which is usually done in the `AbstractEditPart.createEditPolicies()`.

To better understand the chain of responsibilities, I suggest you to have a look at the super implementation of the `TransferDropTargetListener.getCommand()` method.